# How to update Boolean value in object array using axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I am creating a simple todo app with react js and node js , if  I tick the check box status update to true using axios how it work

the post method

```
app.post('/Todo',function(req, res){

    lists.push({ "toDo": req.body.list, "id": new Date(), "status": false})
    console.log(lists)
    res.status(200).json(lists[lists.length-1])

})
```

Comment: What is `lists`?

Comment: @lpizzinidev it is object array name, (const lists =[
    {id: new Date(),toDo:"learn react",status:false}
])